# Lazing loading not working when **build --prod**

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

```
> app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: () => import('./test-lazy-loading/test-lazy-loading.module').then(m => m.TestLazyLoadingModule)
  }
];
```

```
ERROR
GET http://localhost/styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2localhost/:12 GET http://localhost/runtime-es2015.eb2b81c6532ef7a6ad37.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

it working when run **ng serve** but when build **ng build --prod** then it not working.
please help me! thanks

Comment: Did you resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked everywhere but have not found any better solution than building with *aot* (Ahead Of Time) compilation disabled.
Running `ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false` will do the trick.
You can also disable aot in `angular.json`

```
{
   "projects":{
      "<your-project-name>":{
         "architect":{
            "build":{
               "configurations":{
                  "configurations":{
                     "production":{
                        "aot":false
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The difference between aot and jit (just in time) is that modules are compiled on the fly in jit, just like in development mode with `ng serve`.
This results in faster compilation but might impact your performance in production.

At the time aot does not seem to support aot or loadchildren.